# remove sub-category of Custom Post Type from permalink structure

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I've got my permalinks for a Custom Post Type set to /%custom_taxonomy%/%postname%/ using the Custom Post Type Permalink Plugin to set the custom rules for this CPT.

What this gives me is site.com/cpt/term/sub-term/postname. Yes the post is in the sub-term.

What I want is site.com/cpt/term/postname, so eliminate the sub-term from the permalink.

Looking at this question [Remove child category from URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147453/remove-child-category-from-url/147464) and then the code https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L169 you can see that the CPT's don't get to the same filter. CPT's use get_post_permalink here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L244

That only leaves me with the post_type_link filter.

How would I achieve site.com/cpt/term/postname?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up with. Needs some clean up on my end still but it works.

https://gist.github.com/curtismchale/fa8d0570ce2c9b14880f31766c560872